# Could not click on ArrayList Items

Tags: java, android, xml, android-arrayadapter

[I created a project that uses an ArrayList to store data and when I click on each item on the list view it starts a new activity, after that I added image button to the ListView
now the app is lunching correctly but when I click on items nothing happens.][1]

**Main java code:**

```
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
    
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    
            // Create an ArrayList of MusicApp objects
            ArrayList<Music> music = new ArrayList<Music>();
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover1, "Title1", R.drawable.cover1));
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover2, "Title2", R.drawable.cover1));
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover3, "Title3", R.drawable.cover1));
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover4, "Title4", R.drawable.cover1));
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover5, "Title5", R.drawable.cover1));
            music.add(new Music(R.drawable.cover6, "Title6", R.drawable.cover1));
    
            AndroidMusicAdapter musicAdapter = new AndroidMusicAdapter(this, music);
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(musicAdapter);
    
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    startActivity(position);
                }
            });
        }
    
        public void startActivity(int position) {
    
            if (position == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song1Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song2Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song3Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song4Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song5Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song6Activity.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

***Adapter code***

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    
    public class AndroidMusicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Music> {
        public AndroidMusicAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Music> music) {
    
            super(context, 0, music);
        }
    
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    
            // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
            View listItemView = convertView;
            if (listItemView == null) {
                listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }
    
            // Get the {@link Music} object located at this position in the list
            Music currentMusic = getItem(position);
    
            // Find the ImageView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID list_item_icon
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
            // set the image to iconView
            iconView.setImageResource(currentMusic.getImageResourceId());
    
            // Find the TextView in the list_item.xml layout with the ID song_name
            TextView nameTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.song_name);// Get the version name from the current AndroidFlavor object and
            // set this text on the name TextView
            nameTextView.setText(currentMusic.getSongName());
    
            ImageButton playButton = (ImageButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
            playButton.setImageResource(currentMusic.getPlay());
    
            //Return the whole list item layout (containing 1 textView &nd 1 imageView)
            return listItemView;
    
        }
    }
```

***methods code***

```
        public class Music {
        
            // Drawable resource ID
            private int mImageResourceId;
        
            // Name of the song
            private String mSongName;
        
            // play button
            private int mPlay;
        
            public Music(int imageResourceId, String songName, int play) {
                mImageResourceId = imageResourceId;
                mSongName = songName;
                mPlay = play;
            }
        
            public int getImageResourceId() {
                return mImageResourceId;
            }
        
            public String getSongName() {
                return mSongName;
            }
        
            public int getPlay() {
                return mPlay;
            }
        }
```

***layout code***

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp">
        
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playButton"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />
        
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/list_item_icon"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp" />
        
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/song_name"
                    style="@style/titleStyle"/>
        
        
            </LinearLayout>
```

***listView code***

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Try adding a log inside onItemClick or maybe instead of starting an activity to get the clicked item position and check if there is any response. Or simply try showing a toast.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code need improvements but to solve your problem you can add to your ***Adapter code*** `listItemView.setOnClickListner(and implement method click listener)` and move your function startActivity to ***Adapter code*** and finally put startActivity inside **listItemView.setOnClickListner** and remove `listView.setOnItemClickListener` from your **Main java code**

**Note**: edit startActivity `new Intent(MainActivity.this, Song1Activity.class)` with `new Intent(getcontext(), Song1Activity.class)` After move to your adapter

```html
    public void startActivity(int position) {
    
            if (position == 0) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song1Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 1) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song2Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 2) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song3Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 3) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song4Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 4) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song5Activity.class));
            }
            if (position == 5) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getcontext(), Song6Activity.class));
            }
        }
    }
```